# Lexing Errors vs Parsing Errors

Tags: compiler-construction

I am writing a compiler for a more complicated language than I remember doing in school. It is still simple, but I am running into problems with separation of concern. Compiler construction class held our hand too much I guess...

I understand parsing errors are generally syntactic errors. For example a string like `111a111` might be parsed as `NUMBER IDENTIFIER NUMBER` since each construct in this string is a valid lexing according to the grammar. So the lexer wouldn't error here, the parser would error when it goes to validate a `VALUE` production (for example) and discovers an identifier.

If this is the case, than anything a regular expression can match is considered a valid lexeme, and the parser handles everything else.

Given this, what would constitute a lexer error? I could guess anything that wouldn't be a valid lexeme (for example, a Japanese letter might not be lexed according to the grammar) but is there anything else? Mentally, I am trying to build a model of where I should separate the concern between the lexer and the parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic case of an input which cannot be tokenised is an unterminated string literal. Tokenising of languages with delimited comments (such as C) can also fail when the closing delimiter is absent.

Individual languages might also have idiosyncratic tokenisation errors, such as digits out of range in numeric constants with explicit bases. (Eg. `7#715` in a language where the `N#` prefix means "base *N*".)

In some cases, it will prove most convenient to pass these exceptional cases to the parser as a "bad token" token, rather than try to reduplicate error recovery code. (Although recovering from an unterminated string error might be unnecessary, at least in languages which allow multiline strings.) In other cases, such as the bad integer token, error recovery probably consists of substituting the bad token for a valid one of the same type; in that case, the lexer needs to have access to the mechanism which associates errors with the input stream.